# React Image Preloading with a timed Image Switcher are delayed longer than they should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-preloader

I have seen many ways to preload images in react, and have had success with a few different solutions.. but I am having a bit of a glitch with this component switching images.

There is an array of 19 images that are stored in my /public folder that are supposed to switch ever 500ms. To do this I am preloading all 19 images before the `setTimeout` function starts switching them.

I started by preloading them in the /public/index.html file like so... but it did not really work.

```
<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/Img1.jpg" as="image" />
```

So then I decided to try another method by creating promises and loading them into the cache before starting the `setTimeout` function. This is in the code below.

The issue is... both methods are producing the same effect. Sometimes the image switches at 500ms, sometimes its about 2 seconds.

Here is the demo link to see the unexpected delay.
[http://lonewolf6-6009ac63d7e5da3a35dc08e4.c.6004d6b8d7e5da3a35dc04c8.cycle.io/about](http://lonewolf6-6009ac63d7e5da3a35dc08e4.c.6004d6b8d7e5da3a35dc04c8.cycle.io)

Thanks for the advice!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import LW_ABOUTME from './LW_ABOUTME.png';

export default function About() {
  const [aboutImg, setAboutImg] = useState("Img1");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const images = [
      "/images/about-images/Img1.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img2.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img3.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img4.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img5.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img6.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img7.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img8.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img9.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img10.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img11.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img12.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img13.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img14.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img15.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img16.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img17.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img18.jpg",
      "/images/about-images/Img19.jpg",
    ];
    let imgNum = 0;

    const cacheImages = async (srcArray) => {
      const promises = await srcArray.map((src) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          const img = new Image();

          img.src = src;
          img.onload = resolve();
          img.onerror = reject();
        });
      });

      await Promise.all(promises);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    const changeImage = () => {
      setAboutImg(images[imgNum]);
      imgNum <= 17 ? imgNum++ : (imgNum = 0);
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeImage();
      }, 500);
    };
    cacheImages(images);
    !isLoading && changeImage();
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <div id="page-content" className="about-div">
      <div className="about-img-div">
        {isLoading ? (
          <img src="/images/about-images/Img1.jpg" alt="first" className="about-img" />
        ) : (
          <img src={`${aboutImg}`} alt={aboutImg} className="about-img" />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="about-text-div">
        <p className="about-text">
          Zachary Matias aka Lonewolf is a director and editor from the midwest.
          In 2016 he sold his car and purchased a video camera where he would
          shoot his very first music videos for friends and artists around the
          area. After reaching out to Chicago artists, he then started branching
          out and developing his own unique editing style.
        </p>
        <p className="about-text">
          Since then, he has had the pleasure of not only collaborating with but
          befriending some of his favorite artists and creatives and continues
          to do so.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Open the console and look at the network tab. I seriously doubt _that_ is your intent.

Comment: Sure - So preloading is not the problem is what you are thinking? / What should I look for in the network tab?

Comment: You can't miss it :-o)

Comment: Hmm. Looks like it's requesting a new image every time it switches. I could be completely wrong....

Comment: Yes, because of the use of the hook - sense a change - run the hook. So the images are loading over and over. What led you do believe you need to precache/preload the images in the first place?

Comment: That makes sense about the hook. Thanks for pointing me to the network tab. -- I was thinking they needed to preload as if they started to switch every 500 ms before loaded on the screen, then only part of the image would show before switching.

Comment: If you have time, read this (focus on Preload Scanner): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work - Then, read about the _timing of the load event_ here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading - you may find that you don't really need to pre-load (all of) the images. If in the raw HTML (not rendered by React), the images will come down at 3-5 at a time (simultaneously). As you've constructed this, they build up a connection request, download file, tear down the connection and repeat every time. This is costly and wasteful.

Comment: Very cool. Eager loading is a new word for my vocabulary. -- So.. if I am understanding this correctly... My images are currently loading eagerly. So my document must fetch every image before it can fire. It seems this is what I need as lazy loading would allow for blank spots on the page if the images are changing every 500ms. -- Then my new question is... Is there a way to only request the image once and and use it multiple times as my script loops through the array, hence preventing that costly and wasteful request?

Comment: First, don't use React, put them in static `<img>` tags with normal source attributes. Allow the first 5 to be eager and the rest to be lazy. You _should_ be pleased, everything else being equal. The example code on the HTMLImageELement page gives a good reference.

Comment: I can give this a try. How would you suggest to switch the image every 500ms then, without react. Just js?

Comment: No, my intent was not for you to remove React totally, just don't use React to cache/pre-load the images. By all means use React (or whatever - don't want to commit blasphemy) to animate your image rotation.

Comment: It is working very nicely locally! Thanks for the help, Randy!  I will say it was not fun to put 19 image tags in there... thankfully there were only 19!

Comment: The only acceptable cut-n-paste! LOL - glad to help. Have fun.